# Is it enough to prove that $x \not \succsim^* y$?

Tags: microeconomics, mwg

I'm trying to negate that: $\exists B \in \mathcal{B}$ such that $x,y \in B$ and $x \in C(B)$.

Looks that the negation is equivalent to: $\forall B \in \mathcal{B}(x,y \in B \implies x \not \in C(B))$. Is it right?

Comment: This is more appropriate for math.se no? Whilst it fits into the context of economics I don't see how economics would help you prove this...

Comment: Once the appropriate meaning is attached to these letters it becomes an economics question. MWG is one of THE standard textbooks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is. Step by step:

$\lnot \exists B \in A (x,y \in A \land x \in C(B))$ is equivalent to

$\forall B \in A \lnot(x,y \in B \land x \in C(B))$ is equivalent to

$\forall B \in A (x,y \notin B \vee x \notin C(B))$ is equivalent to

$\forall B \in A (x,y \in B \implies x \notin C(B))$.

Reference: [How to prove it, by Velleman](https://www.amazon.com.br/How-Prove-Structured-Daniel-Velleman/dp/0521675995)